# Execution of C program and special keys (arrows)

Tags: c

If I am executing a C program, what are the symbols that show up when I hit the arrow keys, for example? What can be done with these? See below.

```
What is that maximum number of type double entries?
2
Enter the values, q to quit:
324
-9^[[A
Here are your 2 entries:
 324.00
  -9.00
```

Comment: Arrow keys are **multi-byte** values that can vary by compiler and platform. There are multiple post already on StackOverflow that describe their use. The are part of your terminal input. You generally just need to backspace over them if you make a mistake.

Comment: ascii: 27 91 65-68 (tested on cygwin)

Comment: Look up `terminfo` for your OS.